# Date module is missing but it's exisit

Tags: 7, datetime

I have installed Date module since i made drupal installation, i built many date fields but Suddenly this message show up when i go to my content type's manage field page "Inactive fields are not shown unless their providing modules are enabled.

The following fields are not enabled:(here my date field and tell me date module is not enabled)"

When open modules page can't find date module but other sub modules exist like (date tools, date views ....)

I tried to recopy the date module and nothing change, date module still lost.

All my date fields disabled please help, thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can check for missing modules here and maybe its just a disconnect try this [Missing Modules](https://drupal.org/project/missing_module) or these responses here can help you list your modules http://timonweb.com/advice-may-help-you-if-your-drupal-7-has-started-run-slowly

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions and owners of the date module folder inside your sites/all/modules it should be same as others...

Check drupal watchdog logs for more information on errors....

Comment: permissions is 755 for all folders and files in module folder already

Comment: Did you check logs.. ? Can you see info file inside date module ? can you check permissions of date.info file ?

Comment: yes all there, date.info and date.module  and all the test files. the permissions of the files is 755

Comment: Open and read the module's info file, in case it has been damage during the upload.

Check the permissions of that module's folder (is it at least 755?) and of the .info file (is it at least 644?).

Look for differences in permissions and owner between a module that works and one that doesn't work.

Check uninstall tab and see your module is listed there... Try Uninstalling & installing...

Comment: thanks for your help, i did what you say and the permission what it should, i tried to uninstall all the sub date module and remove the date module files and recopy new files but it's the same